# Hiding registry activity

Tags: c#, .net, security, registry, regedit

**The Project:** I am currently developing a security system and the system relies on the registry for support.

**The Problem:**
If someone managed to locate the registry key I am using, that person could bypass the system. 
**I need to be able to avoid Registry Monitors and other software so that activity with the registry key would be hidden.**

Does anyone know how to do this or is there a better method I could use for this purpose?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure this is security software and not malware you want to develop?

Comment: That is what security permissions are for. You can set security in the registry just as well as in the file system. (And if you are trying to hide/lock a value from Administrators of the local system - don't).

Comment: Making Windows resources disappear requires a rootkit.  Google "sony".

Comment: Oded: I am not developing malware, just to be absolutely clear. This is a licensing module for my companies products. We want to distribute different licenses for people to use our software.

Comment: Javed: That doesn't sound like a solid solution, sorry :)

Comment: Viktor, I'm pretty sure @Javed was being cynical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you trying to hide your software from administrators? The administrator owns the machine, and normally only malware tries to hide itself from machine owners.

There are rootkit-type techniques that will work against most detection attempts. But if you have to resort to that type of technique, your software will resemble a true rootkit. This is normally a bad thing - in fact, some AV (and tools like RootkitRevealer) will find your software and kill it. Are you sure you want to engage in that type of battle?

It's hard to advise on a suitable alternative without knowing what you're trying to protect or prevent. Your first action should be to create a [threat model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threat_model). Then you might want to look at techniques involving a [digital certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate) to keep your private information secret and free from non-detectable tampering. Your app can legitimately install its own digital certificate without your customer ever being aware.

**Edit**: In answer to your comment, the best way of ensuring that certificate removal is detected is to "phone home" during install with a hash of the machine's identity. The hash identifies the machine uniquely without giving you any information about the machine. There are licensing schemes that will do all this for you, such as [Desaware's licensing system](http://www.desaware.com/products/licensingsystem/index.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

No I think it would be unwise to engage in a RootKit battle :)

The digital certificate idea is good but doesn't fit our project as we dont want users to be required to install a certificate.

Comment: @Viktor: your app can install a digital certificate without your customer ever being aware.

Comment: Can we somehow make sure that the digital certificate will not be uninstalled? That would reset our license knowledge of the particular machine.

Comment: Yes your solution sounds good but as we want to offer off-line usage of our products so this solution will not be sufficient. Thanks for all the replies:)

Comment: @Viktor: the phone-home is only needed at install-time, not during normal operation. Or do you want to enable everything to be offline, even installation?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Offering that is simply the downfall of some kind of a "bullet-proof" solution. The Desaware idea would have worked if we could have set that as a constraint. 
I guess we are dealing with the same problem as the gaming industry here.

Answer (score 1):

Not foolproof in any way, but you could look for the most common ones (like RegMon and Process Explorer etc) and if you find any off them running you can put up a dialog telling the user that he has to disable them to be allowed to continue. You'd have to keep checking for those though so that he doesn't start it again after the install starts.
I think this is what the copyprotection for some games do.

Though I'd thought the user could just export most/all sections of the registry in text format before the installation and then again afterwards and just do a compare so even if you could make sure that nothing was running you'd still not be able to make sure that your changes couldn't be found.

Answer (score 1):

The correct thing to do is design a system that cannot be bypassed simply by knowing the registry keys used.